# TemplateUrl de acordo com propriedade do objeto

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Olá,

Eu tenho um controller com uma array ($scope.fields) com vários objetos dentro: cada objeto é um input de formulário diferente (ex: input, select, checkboxes). Já estou usando o ng-repeat pra iterar sobre eles, porém preciso que cada um carregue um templateUrl diferente de acordo com a propriedade Type do próprio objeto.

Qual é o método ideal para fazer isto usando Angular? (v1.5.7)

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que seria isso que você quer -> [aqui](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/)

Comment: É exatamente o que eu estava procurando! Obrigado :)